# Why "meth-", "eth-", "prop-", when there is "uni-","di-","tri-"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

In chemistry, the homologous series for hydrocarbons uses the following prefixes:

> - Meth-
> - Eth-
> - Prop-
> - But-
> - Pent-
> - Hex-
> - Hept-
> - Oct-

Why are these prefixes used, instead of just using "uni-", "di-", "tri-"?

I looked up the prefixes, but there is no dictionary record of them. Still, I think "uni-", "di-", "tri-", were invented first.

Is there a specific reason why, instead of using the normal counting prefixes, new prefixes were used or made up, assuming they were made up for this specific purpose?

Comment: Not sure if you care, but the uni-, di-, and tri-, etc, work into the complex molecule nomenclature, to designate how many side groups of a particular type are on a chain.  For instance, 18-bromo-12-butyl-11-chloro-4,8-diethyl-5-hydroxy-15-methoxytricos-6,13-dien-19-yne-3,9-dione has two ethyl groups, two double carbon bonds, and two oxygen molecules.

Comment: This doesn't seem a question specific for English; In Italian, the used prefixes are _met-_, _et-_, _prop-_, _but-_. It seems more a chemistry question.

Comment: 4-dimethylaminoazobenzene-4'-sulfonic acid sodium salt (methyl orange).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Short answer: they were invented to preserve names of organic substances that already were in use. From [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_prefix) on number prefixes:

> The IUPAC nomenclature of organic chemistry uses the numerical prefixes derived from Greek, except for the prefix for 9 (as mentioned) and the prefixes from 1 to 4 (meth-, eth-, prop-, and but-), which are not derived from words for numbers.
>
> These prefixes were invented by the IUPAC, deriving them from the pre-existing names for several compounds that it was intended to preserve in the new system:
>
> - **methane** (via methyl which is in turn from the Greek word for wine),
> - **ethane** (from ethyl coined by Justus von Liebig in 1834),
> - **propane** (from propionic which is in turn from pro- and the Greek word for fat), and
> - **butane** (from butyl which is in turn from butyric which is in turn from the Latin word for butter).

Comment: I was surprised since wine (ideally) doesn't contain methyl alcohol.  From wikipedia:  French chemists Jean-Baptiste Dumas and Eugene Peligot, after determining methanol's chemical structure, introduced "methylene" from the Greek methy = "wine" + hȳlē = "wood" (patch of trees) with the intention of highlighting its origins, "alcohol made from wood (substance)", but with Greek language errors: the Greek for "wood (substance)" is xylo-. The term "methyl" was derived in about 1840 by back-formation from "methylene", and was then applied to describe "methyl alcohol".

Comment: @NeilG: Why do you say hûlê was not used for the substance wood? As far as I know, it can very well be so used: http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=lsj&lang=el&word=u%28%2flh&filter=CUTF8