# Is there a reason to use "mono" over "uni"?

Tags: prefixes, neologisms

I'm just interested in knowing if there is any non-arbitrary basis for using prefixes "mono" or "uni" when words are initially being coined. As far as I can tell, they mean the same thing as a prefix. For example, why use "monochrome" instead of "unichrome"?

In a similar vein, what about other words, with prefixes like "bi", "di" or "duo"?

To be more specific, I suppose I wondered if there was any inherit connection between the prefix and its root word; like maybe if the root word is from Latin, the Latin prefix should be used, or something.

Comment: This is a super interesting question! I do wonder if there's any kind of significant rule, or if it's all just random.

Comment: Related prefix questions: [What is the origin of the counting prefixes: uni-, bi-/di-, tri-, quad-, etc.?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23348/what-is-the-origin-of-the-counting-prefixes-uni-bi-di-tri-quad-etc), [Why "meth-", "eth-", "prop-", when there is "uni-","di-","tri-"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28372/why-meth-eth-prop-when-there-is-uni-di-tri)

Answer (score 15):

<sup>I’m gonna have to disagree with @prash, and so I’ll post this as a competing answer, offering an alternative take on The Rule:</sup>

1. The prefix *[mono-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mono-)* comes from Greek *monos*, itself rooted in the Proto-Indo European **men-* (small). *[uni-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=uni-)* comes from the Latin *unus*, itself from PIE *oinos* (and thus related to the Greek *oinos*, “ace on a dice”; Ancient Greek otherwise used *alpha* for the number one).
2. Forming words from mixed Latin and Greek roots **used to be frowned upon**. In the classical tradition, you would form things either from Greek or Latin, not mix them together.
3. As time evolved, **a number of Greek and Latin roots entered the English lexicon, mostly as suffixes and prefixes**. Because they became part of the language in that way, they could be combined with other words, being somewhat free of the older rules: you wouldn’t go forging a brand new words directly from Latin and Greek roots, but you would add a prefix (say, *auto*) that came from Greek but was now assimilated into the English language, and put it in front of an English adjective (say, *mobile*, which came from Latin *movere* through Middle French). And kaboom, you have: automobile. And few frown upon it.
4. So, what's the current status? **It's now mostly a matter of taste**. There is no strict rule, and you should form the word that sounds better to your ears.

Wikipedia calls words formed with roots of different languages [hybrid words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word), though I've never really heard the term used. I’d prefer we call them ***[heteroradicals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29042/what-do-i-call-a-word-with-roots-from-multiple-languages/29043#29043)*** (tip of the hat to JSBᾶngs).

Moreover, the Wikipedia article linked above has a long list of such English words, many of which are very common: *homosexual*, *television*, *hyperactive*, *electrocution*, *bigamy*, *Minneapolis*, etc. It even includes the following two words which have the *mono-* prefix:

- monoculture
- monolingual

---

**TLDR** — I usually don't do [tldr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read)’s, but this has turned into a general post on the topic while you had a very specific question. So, here's the answer to your very specific point: ***it's a matter of taste, choose the one that sounds best.*** If the roots are from the same language, as an added bonus it will please some more people.

Comment: I agree. While "mono" and "uni" may be different sources, they are now part of English.

Comment: @Bogdan “when words are initially being coined” (to quote the OP) sounds a lot like creating words to me

Answer (score 5):

*Mono* is from Greek and is the preferred prefix for words with Greek roots. That's why *monochromatic* exists, and *unichromatic* doesn't.

*Uni* is from Latin and is the preferred prefix for words with Latin roots. That's why *unidimentional* exists, and *monodimensional* doesn't.

Not everyone knows these rules now, and so, happily combine words with Greek and Latin roots when coining new words. That's why we have *monorail*.

Comment: If mono is one, and poly is several, what do you make of monopoly?

Comment: @user11761: it's not the same poly: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/monopoly

Comment: Oh ok. poly is from the greek word for 'to sell' and not 'many'.

Answer (score 2):

*Uni-* is used to mean "one; having or consisting of one."
*Mono-* is used to mean:

- one; alone; single
- with an extreme, singular character to the point of dominance or exclusion

There is an overlap of meanings, but (for example) you say *monopoly* and not *unipoly*; *monolithic* and not *unilithic*.

*Di-* is used to mean "twice; two-; double."
*Bi-* is used to mean:

- two; having two
- occurring twice in every one
- occurring once in every two
- lasting for two
- doubly; in two ways

Also in this case, there is an overlapping of meanings, but *bi-* is used in cases where *di-* is not used; for example, you say *bimonthly* or *biannual*, but not *dimonthly* or *diannual*.

Comment: This is kind of missing the point. Why "di" and not "bi", or vice versa?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the meanings. It’s *monolithic* and *monopoly* because the second elements of the compounds are from Greek *λίθος* (*líthos*) 'a stone' and *πωλέω* (*pōléō*) 'sell', respectively.

Comment: I fail to see the point. Are you saying that English doesn't use a prefix derived from Latin with a word derived from Greek, or vice versa? In that case, there should not be a word like _monoamine_, since _amine_ derives from a Latin word.

Comment: I think kiamlaluno is right. To sharpen the answer a bit: “mono” is reporting an ambient condition, such as “monolingual”, whereas “uni” is reporting something brought about, such as a “unisex” haircut.